Troubleshooting a .NET call to SQLite; issue with slow speed
I have two servers, A and B, which I believe to be exactly the same specification. They are both dedicated servers. Both are Windows 2012 RE environment and I have set up the exactly the same software on each. I have checked almost all pragma settings and they are exactly the same.
On these servers I am running a very simple .NET application - built for the purposes of this entry in Stackoverflow - that calls a SQLite database once every two seconds and performs an UPDATE. I have logging to monitor the speed of these calls to SQLite.
On server A (named 16gig on the chart) it is fast and on server B (named 17gig) it is very slow. Zero millisecs verus 31 to 39 millisecs. See my chart attached.
Here is the chart :
Higher Values on Server B than Server A
I am trying to discover what I have set up differently on Server B from Server A. I have checked all pragma settings and any other configurations that I can think of and they are all exactly the same across both servers.
Any ideas for other checks would be very gratefully received.
Here is the code I used for this Test:
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FIX_SQL_Lite;

namespace SQLite_Test_App_2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("System started! Lets Wait 5 seconds");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

            Int64 i = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                FixOrders_DataBase.Set_Orde_tx_statusbroker(965668, "Test_" + i.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Order Executed!");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}

